# Bernoulli trials probability

Tags: probability

In 10 Bernoulli trials find  the conditional probability that all successes will occur consecutively, given that the number of successes is between four and six.

The answer is :
$$(7p^4q^6 + 6p^5q^5 + 5p^6q^4)
/\sum_{k=4}^{6}\binom{10}{k}p^kq^{10-k}$$

I understand almost everything in that solution except why the coefficients (7, 6 and 5) are there.

Thank you very much

Comment: Given there are $n$ i.i.d. trials and $k$ successes, the probability the successes are consecutive is $\dfrac{n-k+1 }{\displaystyle{n \choose k}}$

Comment: @Henry thanks! that's it. could you please tell me how did you get that formula. tank you

Answer (score 0):

$$(7p^4q^6 + 6p^5q^5 + 5p^6q^4)
/\sum_{k=4}^{6}\binom{10}{k}p^kq^{10-k}$$

Comment: how you got there? thanks

Comment: You have to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: To the one who downvoted...do you really think i should show the entire solution to a question like this?

Comment: i've updated the question. thanks